# Setting focus to another control prevents current control value from changing in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a ComboBox in a WinForms app written in VB.NET. In the .SelectionChangeCommitted event I want to change the focus to a different specific control to assist user workflow. However when I do that, the change is not saved on the initial ComboBox and the value & index are reverted to the original values.

I've used both myControl.Focus and myControl.Select

The Combobox is setup like this:

```
        With ChoosePartType
            .DisplayMember = "PartName"
            .DataSource = GetTable(qry) 'This custom function returns a DataTable with fields PartNum and PartName
            .ValueMember = "PartNum"
            .SelectedIndex = -1
        End With
```

I assume something in the changing focus is short-circuiting the property change. Is there a way to force that to happen before I change focus?

Note: seems like a different issue from [WInforms Combobox SelectionChangeCommitted event doesn't always change SelectedValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844567)

Similar to this but I don't use databindings: [Combobox DataBinding Bug - Won't write value if programmatically losing focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17556487)

Comment: Do you also change the text or some other property of the target Control? Is it bound to the same data source? If you `BeginInvoke()` the other Control, as in `SomeControl.Text = [ComboBox].GetItemText([ComboBox].SelectedItem) BeginInvoke(New Action(Sub() SomeControl.Focus()))`, what happens?

Comment: Using BeginInvoke works - the ChoosePartType control stores the updated SelectedIndex.  Can you make that an answer? And also explain why that fixes it?

Comment: I assumed that your controls were all bound to the same datasource. The CurrencyManager needs to set the Current position before the change is committed. If you set the Text (or other bound Property) of another Control bound to the same datasource, you set the record in edit mode while not yet committed, reverting Current. Moving the focus in the meanwhile, causes validation events, so you might end up with the ComboBox Text already set to a value (since `UpdateText()` is called before `SelctionIndexChanged` or `SelectionChangedCommitted` are raised) and the previous SelectedItem value.

Comment: `BeginInvoke()` enqueues the focus change in the Message Queue, so it will be executed *later* (after the edit has been committed). -- The [UpdateText()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ComboBox.cs,3415) method I'm referring to, which is called, for example, [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ComboBox.cs,3593) and [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ComboBox.cs,1659) (also when the handle is created).

Comment: You can post the answer yourself, if you want, using the notes here if you find that what is described here matches the use-case, so you can describe your actual scenario, what is bound to what etc.

Comment: Note, however, that the use of `BeginInvoke()` here is to be considered a *proof of concept*, not an actual solution. The same problem could involve other UI elements in ways that make the consequences hard to predict. IMO, it's better to fix the procedure as a whole.

Comment: Just FYI - I didn't fully answer your question because your solution worked, but the controls in question do not share a datasource and I am also not changing any properties of the control I'm switching the focus to.

Comment: Changing the focus AND setting a property can cause this. If the Control that receive the focus has no property bound to the current datasource, you must have something else that causes validation events and updates bound values (a DataGridView can do that, for example). So you might have explicit `Validate()` calls (or `EndEdit()`, in specific conditions). Or a bound control value is changed when the selection is committed (in this case, you should see that the value is not updated immediately, only when the record is re-selected).

Comment: I don't know enough of what's happening to be more precise. Switching focus alone, with no changes in the datasource when the selection is committed, won't cause this behavior (unless you have DataBinding setup the wrong way, generating plainly *controversial operations*, `Format()` and `Parse()` handlers that don't do their job etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
ChoosePartType.SelectedItem.Row("PartNum")
```

Assuming that this is the first column of the control's datasource, this could be also written as:

```
ChoosePartType.SelectedItem.Row(0)
```